# Connect wamp server in Android

Tags: android, sockets, wampserver

I'm trying to connect with the WAMPServer or want to subscribe to the channel in Android. not connecting in Android but working on the web browser.

I used this library `https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-java`

```
class AutoBhanActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var dataObject:JSONObject
lateinit var rootObject:JSONObject
lateinit var rootObjectDriver:JSONObject
 val key="driver106apikey"


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_bhan)

    dataObject=JSONObject()

    dataObject.put("lat", 123.2123)
    dataObject.put("lng", 22.5543)
    dataObject.put("status", 1)

    rootObject=JSONObject()
    rootObject.put("event", "0")
    rootObject.put("data", dataObject)

    rootObjectDriver=JSONObject()
    rootObjectDriver.put(key, rootObject)
    Log.i("OBJECT----", rootObjectDriver.toString())

    tvText.setOnClickListener {

        val key="driver106apikey"
        val session = Session()
        session.addOnJoinListener(this::demonstrateSubscribe)
        session.addOnJoinListener(this::demonstratePublish)
       // session.addOnJoinListener(this::demonstrateCall)
         //  session.addOnJoinListener(this::demonstrateRegister)
        val client = Client( "wss://dev.xxxx.co.uk/devcall")
        val exitInfoCompletableFuture: CompletableFuture<ExitInfo> = client.connect()
        Log.i("OBJECT----", exitInfoCompletableFuture.get().toString())
       // startSocket()
    }
}


fun startSocket() {
    val connection = WebSocketConnection()
    connection.connect("wss://dev.xxxx.co.uk/devcall", object : WebSocketConnectionHandler() {
        override fun onConnect(response: ConnectionResponse) {
            println("Connected to server------")
        }

        override fun onOpen() {
            connection.sendMessage("Echo with Autobah----n")
        }

        override fun onClose(code: Int, reason: String) {
            println("Connection closed------")
        }

        override fun onMessage(payload: String) {
            println("Received message--------: $payload")
            connection.sendMessage(payload)
        }
    })
}

fun demonstrateSubscribe(
    session: Session,
    details: SessionDetails?
) {
    val subFuture = session.subscribe(key, ::onEvent)
    subFuture.whenComplete { subscription: Subscription, throwable: Throwable? ->
        if (throwable == null) {
            // We have successfully subscribed.
            println("Subscribed to topic----- " + subscription.topic)
        } else {
            // Something went bad.
            println("Subscribed to topic----- " + throwable)
            throwable.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

fun demonstrateCall(
    session: Session,
    details: SessionDetails?
) {

    // Call a remote procedure.
    val callFuture =
        session.call("wss://dev.xxxx.co.uk/devcall", 10, 20)
    callFuture.thenAccept { callResult: CallResult ->
        println(
            String.format("Call result: %s-------", callResult.results[0])
        )
    }
}


fun demonstratePublish(
    session: Session,
    details: SessionDetails?
) {

    val pubFuture = session.publish(key, rootObject)
}

private fun onEvent(
    args: List<Any>,
    kwargs: Map<String, Any>,
    details: EventDetails
) {
    println(String.format("Got event: %s", args[0]))
}

fun demonstrateRegister(
    session: Session,
    details: SessionDetails?
) {

    // Register a procedure.
    val regFuture =
        session.register("com.myapp.add2", this::add2)
    regFuture.thenAccept { registration: Registration ->
        println(
            "Successfully registered procedure: " + registration.procedure
        )
    }
}

private fun add2(
    args: List<Any>,
    kwargs: Map<String, Any>,
    details: InvocationDetails
): CompletableFuture<InvocationResult>? {
    val res = args[0] as Int + args[1] as Int
    val arr: MutableList<Any> = ArrayList()
    arr.add(res)
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
        InvocationResult(
            arr
        )
    )
}
}
```

No Error showing in android

this is how data is getting sent through the browser.

[image]

[autobahn.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oIRHZamIaRGm_IQOZgHIU_qw4sYixSCY/view?usp=sharing)
[socket.htlm](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nxIJzMaMRNOp14gOfEmoK6HLv65QywXn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Does it work in the webbrowser of your Android device? You are using a device or an emulator?

Comment: no actually, I ran `socket.html` in the browser so there it is working

Comment: I think you did not give the info i asked for.

Comment: I give up. Sigh..

Comment: @blackapps you want me to run in android browser ;(

Comment: Are you using a device or an emulator? Are android and wamp in the same network? Can you access wamp's something in android? Ping each other?

Comment: @NícolasSimsBotelho in device, both are on same network.

Comment: Did you check if android can get wamp server ip? You can try start wifi hot spot from wamp server pc and connect android

Comment: @NícolasSimsBotelho I don't have server IP, actually, the web socket is live and above aautobhan.js  file for testing on the web browser

Comment: I got it, but how android will connect to wamp? It must connect right?

Comment: @NícolasSimsBotelho i don't have any idea, android can connect or not lo=ike a java web app. is it possible with the above library ?